# The ConnectionString property has not been initialized Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

The underlying provider failed on Open.

> Error Short Description : The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.
>   Error Inner Description :
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection(Boolean shouldMonitorTransactions)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.b__5()
>      at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1..GetEnumerator>b__0()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.b__1[TResult](IEnumerable`1 sequence)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult](IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.DbQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
>      at System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
>      at SKAI.BusinessLayer.AnalysisTreatmentBL.GetAdviceDetails(Int32 KeywordId)
>      at SKAI_Dev.Controllers.Analysis.KeywordAnalysisController.GetNeedAdviceDetails(Int32 KeywordId)
>      at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
>      at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<>c__DisplayClass2b.b__1c()
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult)

Comment: Hello Viru, welcome to SO! Please check out the [question documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You may want to edit your question to describe a bit more your setup, your configuration, etc... And most important, formulate a question.

Comment: I'd suspect the configuration is invalid or the constructor call. Anyways, for any sort of advice you'd need to state a question and post a minimal working example showing your issue.